# NSDate not pulling date from string

Tags: objective-c

I have a String which looks like this

```
NSString *string = @"2012-04-30T23:59:00+10:00";
```

Right now, I am trying to convert that into NSDate format (So I can store the data in a database at a later stage). Right now, I can't seem to get a date format that works with my current date. I am using

```
NSDateFormatter *assignmentDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                        [assignmentDateFormat setDateFormat:@""];
```

to parse my date but I just cant seem to get the combination right (e.g. YYYY-MM-dd etc.).

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if someone knows how to do the timezone part (+10:00) that would be amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full specification is here: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

(Kinda tricky to find in Apple documentation... bookmark it!)

Edit: OK, try this one: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`

Comment: Don't forget you need to include the T in single quotes '' to treat it as a literal.  And the common mistake of YYYY for year instead of yyyy.  So your format string should look something like: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` plus the time zone format

Comment: Would NSLoging the result work (This is just so I can check if it is working).

Comment: Yes, you can log a NSDate: `NSLog(@"date: %@", (NSDate *)myDate);`

Comment: When I NSLog the date, I get NULL

Comment: Then your date format is incorrect. What does your date format look like?

Answer (score 0):

There are a simple tutorial here: http://www.picksourcecode.com/ps/ct/161110.php

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
NSDateFormatter *assignmentDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [assignmentDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+10:00"];
```

Comment: You forgot the `'T'`, there's a space after `ss` and the timezone is always `+0000` in your line of code. This won't work.

Comment: Not yet, your `T` needs to be enclosed in single quotes. And the timezone may not always be +10:00...

Comment: @Cyrille well it was just an example,a little effort has to be made by him to fix it :)

Comment: Admitted, but then don't write “use this” like it would immediately solve the problem ;)

Comment: @Cyrille yes true :)Hope i helped him :)